# Cannot convert parameter 1 from char to const char for strcmp

Tags: c

I just started using pointers in c. I thought to sort a string by entering the string in the command prompt.

When I try to implement it, I get this error:

```
'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'const char *'
```

Could you please guide me and tell me how to make the code with less pointer and more of array?

```
char *sort(char *sortIt)
{
    char *p =sortIt;
    //p = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char));
    char temp[3];
    int len = strlen(sortIt);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(p[i],p[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,p[i]);
                strcpy(p[i],p[j]);
                strcpy(p[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int ij=0;ij<len;ij++)
      printf("%s", p[ij]);
}

int main(char argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p=argv[1];

    sort(p);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: You are confusing strings and single `char`s, the error message is pretty clear. Read the manual of `strcmp` and `strcpy` first.

Comment: change `char *p` to `const char *p`

Comment: Suspect you want `if(strcmp(&p[i],&p[j])>0)`.  But lots of other issues too.

Comment: If you are comparing a single char don't use `strcmp()`. Just use equality `==`, less than `<` or greater than `>` depending on your sort needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear code is attempting to sort the `char` in a string.  Corrections and ideas noted in code.

```
char *sort(char *sortIt)
{
    // After assignment p & sortIt never change. Only need one of these.
    char *p =sortIt;
    // casting the return of callloc() and malloc() is frowned upon.
    // Note: sizeof(char) is _always_ 1
    //p = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char)); 
    char temp[3];  // Only 1 char is needed.  Best to declare in inner lock
    int len = strlen(sortIt);  // Better to use size_t len,i,j,ij;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
        {
            // Only need to compare p[i] > p[j]
            if(strcmp(p[i],p[j])>0)
            {
                // Only need to swap  p[i] p[j]
                strcpy(temp,p[i]);
                strcpy(p[i],p[j]);
                strcpy(p[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    // Only need to print the string once
    for(int ij=0;ij<len;ij++)
      printf("%s", p[ij]);
// missing return
}
```

Sample solution:

```
char *sort(char *p) {
  size_t len = strlen(p);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      /// As this code changed the order of indexing, maybe p[i] < p[j]
      if (p[i] > p[j]) { 
        char temp;
        temp = p[i];
        p[i] = p[j];
        p[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", p);  // Recommend adding \n
  return p;
}
```

[Edit]

I see trouble with the original `main()` code.  Below is code with suggested changes:

```
int main(char argc, char **argv)
{
    // Good to test if argv[1] is valid.
    if (argc <= 1) return 1;
    // Although legal for historic reasons, best to 
    // char *p=argv[1];  
    const char *p=argv[1]; 
    // Since sort() is going to re-arrange p, either sort() allocates new memory
    //   or we allocate memory here.  Then const char *p is not needed.
    size_t size = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
    char *q;
    q = malloc(size);
    memcpy(q, argv[1], size);
    // sort(p);
    sort(q);
    // Good policy to free allocated memory
    free(q);
    return 0;  // Always good to return a value from main()
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to say with the block of code after "I see trouble with"? It's calling `memcpy` with an uninitialized value as the destination.

Comment: @Andrew Medico Oooops!.  Editing mistake drop the needed `q = malloc(size)`;

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings mean null terminated strings. Therefore most C library functions take advantage of that. For example, `strcmp`, `strcpy`, etc.

So your code is wrong in calling `strcmp(p[i],p[j])` and `strcpy(temp,p[i])` because `strcmp` and `strcpy` deal with `strings` not `chars` and `p[i]` is a char.

To compare chars in C, you can just use `if (p[i] > p[j]) ...`. And for copy a char you can just `char c = p[j];`.

Comment: In C, strings _always_ means null character `'\0'` terminated strings.  Without the `'\0'`, it is just an array of `char` or a pointer to `char`.

Comment: @John Smith. Could you tell me what i should change ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Change all the

```
 p[i], p[j]
```

to

```
 &p[i], &p[j]
```

because you want the const char pointers. In your original case, you will be just looking at chars.

Comment: *`strcmp` expects you to provide it a const char*  Where did you learn that?

Comment: [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), and by const char, I mean const char pointer ofcourse

Comment: That's not my downvote, but I'd say the obvious reason is that your answer doesn't help.  How will `strcpy(temp, p[i]);` work if temp is a `const char[]`?  If you want to change your answer to be correct, focus on the `p[i]`...  what is `p[i]` and why would that cause a problem with `strcpy`?

Comment: You can pass a `char *` to a function expecting `const char *`. Read the example in [your linked page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), did it use `const`?

Comment: @indiv, I agree, and that is the reason why I edited it a while ago.

Comment: @YuHao If a char is defined as `char[n]` where n is a number, then it is automatically a `const char *`. That is the reason why they used it in that example. In this case, the parameter should be changed to a `const char *`

Comment: @indiv, I changed the answer to be more precise, do you agree with me?
If not, please go ahead and edit it, I always want to learn something new :)

Comment: @yesminawaah, if this helped you out, marking it as answer would go a long way :)

Comment: Still wrong. Adding `&` may get the program to compile, but it still won't be **correct** (`temp` will be overflowed if the input string is more than two characters long).